# Delay to do some code before it start in c#

Tags: c#

I'm making some application that generate some text but when I click on my button it's take about 1 or 2 sec after that some message box will shown but I want to increase it to 5 or 6 sec. Here is my code when you click on button :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;
    //my code
    // delay here for 5 or 6 sec
    MessageBox.Show(id);
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `async/await` feature to wait asyncronously so your UI thread will be responsive while you are waiting:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    MessageBox.Show(id);
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Was looking for thisone, but didn't remember anymore how to do it. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a one shot timer with the desired interval. When the timer fires, show your message box.

What you don't want to do is call `Sleep` from your GUI thread because that will block the GUI.

Comment: Well to specify it: He never says that blocking the GUI is not an opportunity, because how his code is written it looks like all the code (and so also the progress-bar-stuff) is done before he wants to delay the code.

Comment: @DatRid Sleeping from the GUI thread blocks the UI. Applications need to service their message queues in a timely fashion.

Comment: Sure, I'm totally with you. Just saying that he never said that it wouldn't be okay. That it is an bad idea in general? Definitely.

Comment: @DatRid It is me that is saying that blocking the GUI is not a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

Just `Thread.Sleep` doesn't help you, since it blocks the UI and the progress bar doesn't get updated. Use `Task.Run`:

```
progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 50;

Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // your long running code
    })
.ContinueWith( () =>
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(id);
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

[Thread.Sleep()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.threading.thread.sleep%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will pause your code.
The time is specified in milliseconds or a time span.

But be warned, the code will totally stop there, and wait till the given time is over.

Comment: This will prevent the UI from updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

will pause your code for 5 seconds...
The parameter of the sleep method is in milliseconds.
But why do you want the Messagebox to wait until it shows up?
Thread.Sleep is considered a code smell most of the times...

edit: this will block the UI-Thread. Use the solution of Selman22 if the UI has to stay responsive

Comment: Tnx but whan I enter this code it said: **Error 1 The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context.**

Comment: @ale_x What you need to do is learn how to read the documentation on MSDN. Search for the `Thread` class on MSDN and read its documentation. This will tell you which assembly to reference, and which namespace you need to use.

Comment: Or just click at the MSDN-Link in my answer. But I would suggest you use the solutions by Patrick Hofman/Selman22!

Comment: @ale_x: you need to include "using System.Threading;" at the top of your class. Like David Heffernan suggested, the truth lies in the msdn documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

The Solution of Selman22 is fine, another way to use the suggested `Thread.Sleep();` without freezing your GUI would be to use a background worker and its progress changed event.
You would be able to do something like a loop with 100 iterations, in each iteration you do a small `Thread.Sleep();` and after each iteration you send a progress changed and update your progress bar.

Background worker would look like this:

```
private void BackgroundWorkerStartEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void BackgroundWorkerCancelBeforeWorkIsDoneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }

    private void DoWorkEvent(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        const int loopnumber = 100;

        for (int i = 1; i <= loopnumber; i++)
        {
            if (worker != null && worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (worker != null) worker.ReportProgress(i * 100/loopnumber);
        }
    }

    private void ProgressChangedEvent(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //...update your progress bar or something.
    }

    private void RunWorkerCompletedEvent(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            //...Do what you do if the backgroundworker go cancelled...
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            //...Error displaying...
        }
        else
        {
            //...Do what you do if it worked fine...
        }
    }
```